# Actionscript double question mark operator

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I can't find anywhere what is the `??` operator in this actionscript code for. What it means? How it could be rewritten?

```
package {
    import flash.utils.*;
    public interface _hur {
        "com.hurlant.crypto.symmetric:ICipher"?? function _foo():uint;    
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not an official operator of the language:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html -  I haven't tried it, but I would imaging that would throw an compiler error.

Comment: LDMediaServices is right - it will throw an error, at least with a regular flash player. Never heard of that. Would love to know IF it can be used and for what :)

Comment: This looks like a text translation mistake.  If you cut-and-paste from ASCII to UTF-8 (or whatever) some characters don't get translated correctly.  
If not that, then someone just mistyped the inline `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's used in C# for getting the first value not null.

In C#: `return ((foo ?? bar) ?? "Both null.");`

In Actionscript 3:

```
if (foo) {
return foo;
} else if (bar) {
return bar;
} else {
return "Both null.";
}
```

[Source/Use in C#](http://weblogs.asp.net/mikaelsoderstrom/archive/2008/01/02/tip-of-the-day-double-question-mark.aspx)